# Why can I not access and reset the width of my bar graph?

Tags: matlab, class, bar-chart, matlab-figure, spacing

My x and y axis are two columns of a structured array.  I only want to plot part of the data.  Yet for some reason, when I index it to do this, and then try to plot it in a bar graph, with this code:

```
figure(1); 
bar_handle = bar(data.time(15:32),data.data(15:32), 'g');
baseline_handle = get(bar_handle,'BaseLine');
set(baseline_handle,'LineStyle','--','Color','red')
set(bar_handle,'width',.5)
```

I get this error:

```
Error using specgraph.barseries/set
The name 'width' is not an accessible property for an instance of
class 'barseries'.
Error in trickyBarGraph (line 40)
set(bar_handle,'width',.5)
```

I don't understand how else to do this.  Also, I tried increasing the width by setting my BarSpacing to zero, but I get a similar error referring to the class of the graph.

Answer (score 2):

Try 'BarWidth' instead of 'width'. If you're just trying to change the width of the plot itself, use the 'XLim' property of the axis. For example:

```
set(gca, 'XLim', 100);
```

Good luck!